# SAPUI5 adding Data to JSON Model from Local Storage

Tags: json, storage, sapui5

I need to add something from my local Storage to my JSONModel that I can use it in a view.xml.

In my function where I build up the JSON Model I read the data I need from the local storage.

```
de.fum.nmp.util.Storage.getItem("amountSync").done(function(amountSync) {
    amountSync = JSON.stringify(amountSync);
}).fail(function() { 
    var i = 0;
});

de.fum.nmp.util.Storage.getItem("newSyncTime").done(function(sSyncime) {
    aSyncTimes = JSON.stringify(sSyncime);
}).fail(function(sError) { 
    var i = 0;
});
```

These two deliver the two data fields I need. After that the JSON Model is build, but that already happened before I implemented the reading from the storage.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

How can I make sure that I add those data to the JSON Model, too?

Comment: We need more code.. how is your current JSON Model built?

Comment: As I am still pretty new to SAPUI5 it is hard to explain for me.

My task was that I have to add the data from the local storage to display in the view. Nothing more said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the property value of the model with the data extracted from localStorage.

```
Ex: this.getView().getModel().setProperty("/amountSync", amountSync );
```

Bind the **amountSync** model property to the control.

```
   var view = this;
   de.fum.nmp.util.Storage.getItem("amountSync").done(function(amountSync) {
     amountSync = JSON.stringify(amountSync);
     view.getView().getModel().setProperty("/amountSync", amountSync );
       }).fail(function() { 
        var i = 0;
     });

    de.fum.nmp.util.Storage.getItem("newSyncTime").done(function(sSyncime) {
        aSyncTimes = JSON.stringify(sSyncime);
        view.getView().getModel().setProperty("/aSyncTimes ", aSyncTimes );
      }).fail(function(sError) { 
        var i = 0;
     });
```

Comment: Then I can use it with the /amountSync to display it in the view, right?

Comment: Yeah. something like this new sap.m.Text({  text : "/amountSync"});

Comment: this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        this.getView().getModel().setProperty("/amountSync",amountSync);
        this.getView().getModel().setProperty("/aSyncTimes",aSyncTimes);

That simply thing is all? :D
I still couldn't use it in the view so far, but adding the two lines is fine?

Comment: Sadly not, the site is just no longer building